# Kotlin bytes vs enums when parsing byte stream

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to parse a byte stream in Kotlin where the pattern is a series of opCode byte followed by arbitrary bytes based on the opCode. So I started up by setting up an enum, something like:

```
enum class OpCode(val code:Byte) {
    foo(1),
    bar(2),
    yak(3),
}
```

So when I'm building my parse loop, I want to write something like:

```
while(stream.available() > 0) {
    val opCode = stream.read().toByte()
    when (opCode) {
        OpCode.foo.code -> { // do foo stuff }
        OpCode.bar.code -> { // do bar stuff }
        OpCode.yak.code -> { // do yak stuff }
    }
}
```

What annoys me is that I constantly have to put the `.code` in there. I would rather do something like:

```
val opCode = OpCode(stream.read().toByte())
```

But it tells me that I can't instantiate an enum instance. Is there a more idiomatic way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to @s1m0nw1's answer which makes the search just once:

```
interface EnumCodesMap<E : Enum> {
    fun values(): Array<E>
    val codesMap = values().associate { it.code to it }
}

enum class OpCode(val code: Byte) {
    Foo(1),
    Bar(2),
    Yak(3);

    companion object : EnumCodesMap<OpCode>
}

...
val opCode = OpCode.codesMap[stream.read().toByte()]
```

Note that something like this can't be built-in, because you can have multiple values with the same `code`:

```
enum class OpCode(val code: Byte) {
    Foo(1),
    Bar(1)
}
```

Edit: you can extract it to support multiple enums, but with some tricks:

```
inline fun <reified E : Enum<E>, K> EnumCodesMap(crossinline getKey: (E) -> K) = object : EnumCodesMap<E, K> {
    override val codesMap = enumValues<E>().associate { getKey(it) to it }
}

interface EnumCodesMap<E : Enum<E>, K> {
    val codesMap: Map<K, E>
}

enum class OpCode(val code: Byte) {
    Foo(1),
    Bar(2),
    Yak(3);

    companion object : EnumCodesMap<OpCode, Byte> by EnumCodesMap({ it.code })
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this at a common superclass level? I think "no" because of type issues? I was toying with how to do it as a generic, but compiler says I can't mix generics and enums. :(

Comment: You can, but the code is quite complicated. The enum itself doesn't need to be generic, that's not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a companion to your enum to add functionality for looking up the relevant enum value:

```
enum class OpCode(val code: Byte) {
    Foo(1),
    Bar(2),
    Yak(3);

    companion object {
        fun of(code: Byte) = values().find { it.code == code }
                ?: throw IllegalAccessException("")
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
while (stream.available() > 0) {
     val opCode = OpCode.of(stream.read().toByte())
     when (opCode) {
         OpCode.Foo -> {}
         OpCode.Bar -> {}
         OpCode.Yak -> {}
     }
 }
```